# Get rid of red highlighting of tab space when editing Fortran in Vim

Tags: vim, fortran, vi

When I code Fortran, and use tabs for indentation, Vim highlights those spaces in red, because in older Fortran the first 6 columns were special and reserved for labels/line numbers and continuation symbols. How can I make Vim stop doing that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, tab is not part of the Fortran character set, and portable code should avoid it. So instead I'd recommend to configure vim to use spaces instead of tabs for indentation, see the "expandtab" option.

Comment: +1, but also note, that in my case it does highlight these spaces when i write threre anything. It just assumes everything is fixed source form.

Comment: Thank you. While looking up the expandtab, I learnt about tabstop, softtabstop, and shiftwidth as well. All very useful and interesting.

Answer (score 15):

stop highlighting <kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
:hi link fortranTab NONE
```

start highlighting <kbd>Tab</kbd>

```
:hi link fortranTab Error
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my terminal. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

Put the following in your .vimrc:

```
let fortran_have_tabs=1
```

Explained in the documentation: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html